# How to tar files based on the file name?

Tags: bash, tar

There are some files in `/var/log`  as below:

```
cron
cron-20200322
maillog-20200329
tallylog
bootscan.log
bootscan.log-20200115.gz
bootscan.log-20200116.gz
```

I want to backup files:`cron;cron-20200322;bootscan.log;bootscan.log-20200115.gz;bootscan.log-20200116.gz` to a **single file** `/mnt/log_backup.tar`
Then,I witer bash shell script as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
backup_dir='/mnt'
tar -cpf $backup_dir/log_backup.tar -C /var/log cron*
tar -cpfr $backup_dir/log_backup.tar -C /var/log boot*
```

Sadly, I got error as below:

```
tar: cron*: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: boot*: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

What's the problem in my shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . /var/log -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "boot*" -print0 | tar -cpf  $backup_dir/log_backup.tar --null -T -
find . /var/log -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "cron*" -print0 | tar -rpf  $backup_dir/log_backup.tar --null -T -
```

I think it's the correct answer,maybe not the best one.
Pls contribute you 2 cents if any better solution,thks!

Answer (score 0):

The globbing of * is evaluated before changing the folder to /var/log.

Check [How to make tar globbing work with the 'change directory' option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71462/how-to-make-tar-globbing-work-with-the-change-directory-option)

Comment: If a question is duplicative, vote to close it as such, don't add an answer. See the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of the [How to Answer page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the Help Center.

Comment: @kittygirl: I suggest to change to /var/log and then run tar command: `cd /var/log && tar -cpf "$backup_dir"/log_backup.tar cron* boot*`. In this way globbing with `*` works.

Comment: @Cyrus,your comment works well.In `bash`,after  `cd anotherfolder`,does the left scripts run in `another folder`?

Comment: @kittygirl: `tar` runs in this case in directory `/var/log`. `&&` ensures that `tar` only runs when `cd` has successfully switched to `/var/log`.

Comment: @Cyrus Post that as an answer.